# Is there any way to simulate Azure CI, ADF, Data bricks, Machine learning, Event hub/Grid alert simulation way?

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm looking for some way to validate that the azure alerts that I set up is working. Manually trigger for these alerts is a very long and very hard way.

is there any tool or way to trigger Azure alerts for Azure CI, ADF, Data bricks, Machine learning, Event hub/Grid alert simulation way?

Comment: Have you tried any approach? Please share the error and blockage if you faced during implementation.

Comment: What exactly is it what you want to validate. Is it the condition of when the alert should be fired or the configuration of the action groups?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula - trying to fail pipeline in ADF to trigger alerts, Run queries in Azure SQL, same manual way to trigger.

Comment: @PeterBons, there are various alerts Azure provides OOB in the portal. I'm trying to generate alerts manually but it's a very time-consuming activity and also there is uncertainty to generating the errors as all I mention are PAAS. if there any tool where I simulate the alert generation in the Azure portal.?

Answer (score 0):

## Triggering Alerts

- Azure Automation Runbooks
- Azure Functions Function Apps
- LogicApps

[image]

### Trigger Azure Automation Runbook

To trigger an Azure Automation Runbook, we’ll need to create an Action Group that calls a runbook. Selected Automation Runbook and the side blade will pop out.

[image]

select your Automation Account which will load all available runbooks.
[image]
I used common alert schema

[image]

### Trigger Azure Function Function App

To trigger any type of alert with Azure Monitor, whether its an Azure Function or an email, you need an Action Group.

Under Azure Monitor select Alerts -> Manage Actions -> Add Action Group
[image]

Give your Action Group an Name, Short Name, select your Subscription and Resource Group. Then give it an Action Name and select Azure Function.

[image]

The resource group is the resource group location of your Azure Function. Click ok and save your Action Group. Make Sure “Use Common Alert Schema” is checked.

### Trigger LogicApp

In your Action Group select LogicApp for the Action Type in the right hand pane, selected your Subscription, Resource Group and then your LogicApp.

[image]

### Add to an Alert

I have 1 Runbook, 1 Function App and 1 LogicApp to my Action Group.

[image]